# Is attaching a WD MyCloudEx4100 to a HP Proliant DL380 a good storage solution for Exchange data?

Tags: windows, exchange, storage

We are having a HP Proliant DL380 Gen7 and the all the bays are loaded with drives. The storage is full now and we need to extend the server storage. There is budget issues and we cant afford large storage solution. This storage will be used to save the Exchange related files and we are planning to go with WD MyCloudEx4100 and disks in it. This will be directly connected to the server via Ethernet. The server OS is Windows 2008.

Will this be a good practise or if any other we need to decide quickly as we have activity to be completed based on this.

Comment: Hi hafz. We don't really do "urgent" here; if your needs are especially urgent, you should probably go through some venue other than asking strangers to donate their time freely to help you out. I edited the title of your question to better summarize what you are asking. That said, I'm not sure if what you are asking is really on topic here in the first place; see [what topics can I ask about here?](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) in our site's [help] for more information.

Comment: `This storage will be used to save the Exchange related files` - Which files exactly?

Comment: Yes, we would like to understand which files you're referencing.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the devices supports iSCSI, then it would be fine as a short term measure. I have run worse. Make sure that you are using gigabit LAN, ideally with a dedicated NIC and switch for iSCSI.

You will need to have the Exchange binaries on the local drive - look at only putting the databases on this device.

Comment: First, turn up your backup frequency.  Definitely stress the "short term" part of this answer.  Keep in mind that this storage device is not an "enterprise" level device, probably has a low performance level compared to the internal drives, and is not likely redundant.  Once you locate what data goes on this device, turn up the rate of backups on your exchange server, and find a solution to expand your storage.  Think rack mount NAS, OR rebuild your server with larger drives.  And I say this a final time to stress how important it is.  Turn up your backup frequency.

Comment: @Sembee : Thanks for the update.I guess NAS will not work out with Exchange and will configure as Iscsi. Can you suggest me with the Exchange binaries part. I didnt get that point

Comment: The place where you have installed Exchange itself.